# Creating XML data structure on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa-touch

Is it correct, that there is no official API by Apple to create a well formed XML?
I searched the web for a while but I just found some external frameworks to create XML data structures.

I need it for a web service call and would prefer a native API by Apple.

Of course I could just put together some Strings, but I think that's not the best way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's libxml2, which is supported API on the iPhone. Nothing higher-level, but there are plenty of third-party wrappers.

Comment: libxml2 is a third party API too, isn't it? Well of course there are plenty third-party wrappers out there, but I was just wondering whether there is something native.

Comment: It's part of the Apple distribution, even if someone else wrote some of the source code.

Comment: Great. That was the missing info for me ;)